# Python mistakes a function for an undefined variable

Tags: python, class, recursion

So, it says that `create` in line 11 is not defined, but it is a recursive function within the class. And In VS Code, it shows me an error at line 6 - it says that I am missing the `self` argument, but when I add it, it requires 3 arguments in line 23 (why, I can't provide an argument for `self`, can I ?)

I already tried it with various variations of adding `self` to the arguments, but nothing worked.

```py
class smarray:
    def __init__ (self):

        self.array = []

    def create(index, dim):
        array1 = []
        if index < len(dim)-1:
            for x in range(0,dim[index]):

                array1.append((create(index+1,dim)))

            return array1
        else:
            for x in range(0,dim[index]):
                array1.append("nul")
            return array1
        if index ==0:
            self.array = array1

t = smarray()

t = smarray.create(0, [3,4])
```

**error TB:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pc/Documents/VS Code Files/Python testing/testing range.py", line 23, in <module>
    t = smarray.create(0, [3,4])
  File "/Users/pc/Documents/VS Code Files/Python testing/testing range.py", line 11, in create
    array1.append((create(index+1,dim)))
NameError: name 'create' is not defined
```

Comment: you forgot `self`: `def create(self, index, dim):` It is unclear what you are trying to do with this class: you create an instance `t`, then you reassign it to the result of a method that returns None... Maybe call `t.create(...)` instead.

Comment: `self` if missing from parameters in your method. Try this: `def create(self, index, dim):...` and when you want to call it then use your instance (`t`) Like this: `t.create(0, [3,4])`

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things needed to be fixed in order for this code snippet to run:

```py
class smarray:
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = []

    def create(self, index, dim):
        array1 = []
        if index < len(dim)-1:
            for x in range(0, dim[index]):
                array1.append((self.create(index+1, dim)))
            return array1
        else:
            for x in range(0, dim[index]):
                array1.append("nul")
            return array1

        if index == 0:
            self.array = array1


t = smarray()
my_array = t.create(0, [3, 4])
```

So, the first fix would be adding the `self` keyword to the `def create()` method signature.

Second, in the line `array1.append(...)` the same `self` keyword had to be added, so we can call the `create` method properly: `self.create()`

And the last one I changed the call to the `create` method as "instance method" and not as "class method" - I hope I understood correctly what you tried to achieve here. You can read more [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/306092/what-are-class-methods-and-instance-methods-in-python).

Pay attention that the last `if index==0` is unreachable, thus the code `self.array = array1` won't be ever executed. I don't quite sure what you were trying to achieve there.

Comment: You may want to point out what you fixed to make your answer more useful and complete.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, thank you, I will edit my answer accordingly!

Comment: I wanted to make a class in which you can create a array with a custom number of "dimensions" and custom "length of those dimensions" automatically. Thanks